# Proving Recursive Sequences Converge using the Harmonic Geometric Mean Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, recursion

My question reads:

For any positive $a,b$, the harmonic mean, $H(a,b)=\frac{2}{\frac{1} {a}+\frac{1} {b}}$ is less than or equal to the geometric mean $G(a,b)=\sqrt{ab}$.

This had to be proven, but I got this. The proof was quite straightforward.

(1)Given that $a,b$ are positive with $a<b$, define two sequences recursively by $x_0=a$, $x_{n+1}=H(x_n,y_{n+1})$ and $y_0=b$, $y_{n+1}=G(x_n,y_n)$. Prove that both sequences converge.

**Thoughts**:  I am not too sure if I understand what exactly $x_{n+1}$ and $y_{n+1}$ are but I think it would be that $x_{n+1}=\frac{2}{\frac{1} {x_n}+\frac{1} {\sqrt{x_n\ y_n}}}$ and then $y_{n+1}=\sqrt{x_ny_n}$.

Then, I was thinking of using the Monotone Convergence Theorem, but I am having a bit of trouble determining the bound for each sequence so I can use the theorem. I am not sure how to begin the induction to show that the sequences are monotone increasing/decreasing to use the Theorem.

**How can I use the fact that the Harmonic mean is less than or equal to the Geometric mean for part (1)?**

(2) Prove that both sequences converge to the same number by considering $y_{n+1}-x_{n+1}$.

I am having trouble with this proof because I am not sure on what to do for part (1). Would induction be best in this case? I do not know how the assuming $b\leq\ 2a$ helps in this case.

Any suggestions?

Comment: For part $(1)$, how about induction? Proposition $P(n)::=x_n\lt y_n$

Comment: If you have $x_n\lt y_n$, then can you compare $\sqrt{x_ny_n}$ to $y_n$?

Comment: Using $P(n)$, show that $x_{n+1}\gt x_n$

Comment: To your first comment - yes. To your second, the idea is to show that $x_n\lt x_{n+1}\lt y_{n+1}\lt y_n$

Comment: Since we have $x_n\lt y_n$, we have $\sqrt{x_ny_n}\lt y_n$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use induction, assume $x_{n-1}\leq x_n\leq y_n\leq y_{n-1}$. Then you can easily prove $x_n\leq x_{n+1}\leq y_{n+1}\leq y_{n}$.  For example, to get $x_{n+1}\leq y_{n+1}$,
$$
x_{n+1}=\frac{2}{{1\over x_n}+{1\over y_{n+1}}}=\frac{2}{{1\over x_n}+{1\over \sqrt{x_ny_n}}}\leq \frac{2}{{1\over \sqrt{x_ny_n}}+{1\over \sqrt{x_ny_n}}}=y_{n+1}.
$$

For the second part,
$$
y_{n+1}-x_{n+1}=\sqrt{x_n y_n}-\frac{2}{{1\over x_n}+{1\over \sqrt{x_ny_n}}}\\
=\frac{\sqrt{y_n}-\sqrt{x_n}}{{1\over \sqrt{x_n}}+{1\over\sqrt{y_n}}}=\frac{y_n-x_n}{\left({1\over \sqrt{x_n}}+{1\over\sqrt{y_n}}\right)(\sqrt{y_n}+\sqrt{x_n})}<\frac{y_n-x_n}{2}.
$$

Comment: @Sam you need to prove $x_n$ is monotone increasing, then you can say $x_n$ has a limit. Same for $y_n$, it decreases hence has a limit. Only the condition $y_n-x_n\to 0 $ can not convince these two sequences converge.

Comment: @Sam Look at my induction, $x_{n-1}\leq x_n\leq y_n\leq y_{n-1}$, this just give the increasing and decreasing conditions $x_{n-1}\leq x_n$ and $y_n\leq y_{n-1}$. More explicitly, the first part i have proved is $x_{1}\leq x_{2}\leq\dots\leq x_{n-1}\leq x_{n}\leq\dots \leq y_{n}\leq y_{n-1}\leq\dots\leq y_{1}.$ Hence they are bounded and monotone.

Comment: @Sam For $b\leq 2a$, I didn't use it, don;t know why you have this condition for your problem.

Comment: @Sam $x_1-x_0=\frac{2}{{1\over a}+{1\over\sqrt{ab}}}-a>0$ iff $b>a$. It is just simple arithmatic, you can check it yourself for $y_n$. Any other  questions about this answer?

Comment: Okay, I actually understand how you got part (b) now as I have taken the time to attempt it myself. Now, from here I would need to use induction correct?